Обособление уточнения с тире
Подскажите пожалуйста, как проставить запятые в этом предложении? Моя версия вот такая, но я не уверена насчет последней запятой, которая стоит перед тире.
Взволнованным голосом прокричал он - крик его тут же растворился в игривом встречном ветре, что так нещадно обдавал прохладой, обжигая шею и щеки, - и залился искристым смехом.

Оформление корректное:
Взволнованным голосом прокричал он — крик его тут же растворился в игривом встречном ветре, что так нещадно обдавал прохладой, обжигая шею и щеки, — и залился искристым смехом.
Вставка обособлена двумя тире, на месте вставки нет знаков: Взволнованным голосом прокричал он  и залился искристым смехом.
Запятая перед вторым тире относится к вставке (закрывает СПП и деепричастный оборот).
Розенталь, пункт 4:
3) перед вторым тире ставится запятая, если этого требует структура второй части основного предложения или вставной конструкции.

Спасибо за правку!  Ну очень корректно!  У меня вторая запятая имеет как бы обобщенный смысл, а скобку  после тройки системный редактор выбросил.

Да, со скобками здесь проблемка, поэтому я выделяю жирным. А главная правка в том, что у вас был пункт 10, хотя там всего 4.

Действительно, четыре, всего-то страничка, теперь запомню.  Это в обособлении приложений их десять.

Спасибо большое за разъяснение!)
